# Not getting expected response data after posting

Tags: c#, asp.net, post, get, httpwebrequest

Earlier on I was having an issue with posting data and getting the response, I was finally able to get the data posted, but the response was not giving me the right results, I went through the webform , and then ran my code with visual studio and compared the webforms using Fiddler and it was populated properly from what I can see.
I then compared both of the results, through the site and through visual studio and compared them and I am not getting the results that I should be and I am not sure why, and been trying for the last couple hours to figure out what I am doing wrong (did post a question earlier and had some guidance with what I am looking to do, so if you seen something like this earlier then all apologies, I had to make it more clear)

here is the code that I wrote

```
 public static string PostMyData()
    {
        // This is where the data is going to be posted
        string url = @"http://www.cpso.on.ca/Public-Register/All-Doctors-Search.aspx";

        // This is the data that i am going to post
        string postData = "manScript_HiddenField=&" +
            "__EVENTTARGET=p%24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24btnSubmit&" +
            "__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&lng=en-CA&p%24lt%24ctl00%24SearchBox%24txtWord=Site+Search&p%" + 
            "24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24txtLastName=Aalders&p%" +
            "24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24txtFirstName=&p%" +
            "24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24grpGender=+&p%" +
            "24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24ddLanguage=08&p%" +
            "24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24grpDocType=rdoDocTypeAll&p%" +
            "24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24grpStatus=rdoStatusActive&p%" +
            "24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24ddCity=Select --%3E&p%" +
            "24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24txtPostalCode=&p%" +
            "24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24ddHospitalCity=Select+--%3E&p%" +
            "24lt%24ctl03%24pageplaceholder%24p%24lt%24ctl03%24AllDoctorsSearch%24ddHospitalName=-1&" +
            "__VIEWSTATE=";

        // Create my request
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.ContentLength = postData.Length;
        req.Referer = @"http://www.cpso.on.ca/Public-Register/All-Doctors-Search.aspx";
        req.Accept = "text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*";
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko";

        // Now its time to write the data that I want to post to the webpage
        using (StreamWriter reqWriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            reqWriter.Write(postData);
        }

        // Get the response/results

        string respData = string.Empty;

        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        {
            // Add response/results to string
            respData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return respData;

    }
```

I set a breakpoint at the return respData, and it should be showing one record but it is showing none.

Here are the pics, one is the webform shown in Fiddler from going through the actual webform..

[image: From Site]

and here is the one when I run it through visual studio, and this has lead me to believe that I posted it properly because it is the same

[image: From VS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the form posts to `/Public-Register/All-Doctors-Search.aspx` but the browser is redirected to `/Public-Register-Info-(1)/Doctor-Search-Results` to display the results. They seem to be using the ASP.NET session to maintain state between the two pages. Since sessions rely on cookies, you'll have to enable cookies on your `HttpWebRequest` by creating a `CookieContainer`...

```
// Create my request
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

Now it should work: [Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sS1jAU)

Comment: Wow, all I was missing was one piece of code. Thanks for clearing that up for me. Another plus is that I didn't know there was a fiddle for ASP.NET until now :-)

Comment: Yep. It's pretty handy. Hope you're not doing anything evil with this.  :)

Comment: I wouldn't even know where to begin to make something evil out of it lol.

Comment: Is there any way you can give me a hand with getting the next page of results? I've tried a number of different things and keeps erroring out trying to get the response of the 2nd page

Comment: WebForms uses the viewstate to maintain state between pages. Grab the viewstate from the first response and send it with the next one. This code could use some major refactoring and error checking but sort of looks like this... https://dotnetfiddle.net/hmFL3q

Comment: Thank you very much, it looks like you've done this before. I spent awhile today trying to figure out how to get the viewstate from the response data, it never dawned on me to get it from the respData string, all the information that I needed seemed to have been in front of me the whole time. I'm going to read up on RegEx tonight, its looks like a good thing to know and understand

Comment: Yeah, I had a lot of experience debugging WebForms back in the day... and I might done these sorts of things once or twice. :) Regex is a quick and dirty way to extract the viewstate. To do it properly, look into the HTML Agility Pack... http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: hehe, once or twice ;-). I actually started using HtmlAgilityPack yesterday, to parse out the table. There's 3 or 4 columns, this is going to be a problem because when I write everything to a csv file, The display is supposed to be LastName, FirstName, StreetAddress, Suite, City, Province, PostalCode, Telephone and Fax. But 8 of those are in one td cell and each row has it. I'm thinking use a collection for the rows, count off the column that has the majority of the data that I need then put those values into an array using br as a delimiter, then create a new row in my table. Am I close?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's right. Don't know much about HAP but I would imagine for each row you can grab the innertext of the td with the address, and from there just split by `<br>`. This might be a good place for regex.

Comment: Well, I was able to take the data from using HtmlAgilityPack, and put it into a string and did some fancy replacing and got the text file looking like I want it, now the next part is to properly extract the data from the text file. Each grouping is delimited by a link (which holds the name and lastname), so every piece of the grouping is on a newline, and I got to figure out how to get the data to its proper columns. I didn't think it was all going to be so difficult lol. Its getting there though. I just wanted to keep you posted.